# How to get in.hasNext() to detect when Ctrl - D is entered into the command prompt?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

so I'm working on a computer science lab currently and I'm stumped on a way to have the `in.hasNext();` method detect whether Ctrl - D is entered at the end of the command line input. Essentially what I mean by this, is that whenever `in.hasNext();` finds Ctrl - D it should output false, right? Now when I try to utilize that, and I try to detect when `in.hasNext();` is false, my program detects a space and ends the loop right there. I'm confused as to why it is doing this. Additionally here is my code for reference:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class processInput {
    
    processInput() {

        int charval;
        int counter = 0;
        String[] inputarray = new String[100];

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your input and put Ctrl - D at the end");

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            inputarray[counter] = in.next();
            System.out.println(inputarray[counter]);
            System.out.println(counter);
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("exited loop");

    }//processInput method

}//processInput class
```

Comment: CTRL-D will work on macos or linux, on windows you use CTRL-Z to indicate end of file.

Comment: as @ElliottFrisch told, i tried in Linux it's working completely fine. try Ctrl+Z if you are using Windows like OS.

Comment: On Windows, entering control-d will close the input stream.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  You wanted the loop to end (i.e., `in.hasNext()` returns `false`) when you hit CTRL-D, yes?  If I'm reading correctly, you said you entered CTRL-D and the loop stopped.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: No, that's not the case. The loop wasn't stopping, and I'm on windows so it was an OS issue. My teacher uses a Mac not a windows computer.